# Xamarin Forms Tabbed page cannot change tab background color

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

I have a Xamarin.Forms tabbed page. When I do the following:

```
public partial class MainPage : TabbedPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BarTextColor = Color.White;
        BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#3F51B5");
        Children.Add(new Batches() { Title = "Batches"});
        Children.Add(new Track() { Title = "Track"});
    }
}
```

I can change the BarTextColor properly, in this case, it does change to white. However, I cannot set the BarBackgroundColor. As you can see in the snippet, it should be a blue color but it is not, it is white. How can I change the background of just the tabs? There is another background property but it sets the background color of the whole page, not just the tab.

Also, related, how do you change the underline color of the selected tab? I cannot find a property for that and by default, it is a hot pink color.

Thanks!

Comment: is this in every os?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane Sorry, should have specified, it is for UWP and Android, not iOS. This is actually another question that I could post that is related. My UWP app is already complete, not using Xamarin. I am now creating an Android app and will use shared code from my UWP app. I wonder if I even need to do Xamarin.Forms or just do Xamarin.Android since I will never have iOS?

Comment: And maybe by doing Xamarin.Android, it will make things easier than forms for my scenario?

Comment: i mainly asked so people know where you have tested your code. Also if you only tested in one OS and if you realize it works on another OS, it makes it the problem of an OS. If the issue is only in a single OS, you will need to fix it in just that OS.

Comment: i wouldn't recommend Xamarin.Android unless you have a lot of custom UI and really don't want it cross platform.